# How can I use Plesk's ssl certificate in mercure docker container correctly and make the server work?

Tags: plesk, caddy, mercure

I have a docker mercure container running on plesk. but he is not available.
Now I try to load the ssl certificate manually, but unfortunately that doesn't work.
The server still tries to get certificate from issuer.

here are my variables for the docker container

```
volumes:
     /etc/caddy/Caddyfile : /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/mercureconfig/Caddyfile
     /ssl : /usr/local/psa/var/certificates
Environment variables:
     MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: my_secret
     MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: my_secret
     CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: mydomain
     MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: cors_origins my_domain
```

here is my Caddyfile

```
{
    order mercure after encode

    {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
}

{$CADDY_EXTRA_CONFIG}

{$SERVER_NAME:mydomain:port} {
    tls  /ssl/5snsn456 /ssl/5snsn456
    }
    encode zstd gzip

    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }

    {$CADDY_SERVER_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}

    header / Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    respond / `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <title>Welcome to Mercure</title>
    <h1>Welcome to Mercure</h1>
    <p>The URL of your hub is <code>/.well-known/mercure</code>.
    Read the documentation on <a href="https://mercure.rocks">Mercure.rocks, real-time apps made easy</a>.`

    respond /healthz 200
    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

i am a little further now, it seems like he is accepted my certificates

```
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9011054,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
{"level":"warn","ts":1705198357.906006,"msg":"Caddyfile input is not formatted; run 'caddy fmt --overwrite' to fix inconsistencies","adapter":"caddyfile","file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","line":3}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9332263,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint started","address":"localhost:2019","enforce_origin":false,"origins":["//localhost:2019","//[::1]:2019","//127.0.0.1:2019"]}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9337673,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc000272200"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9525166,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"skipping automatic certificate management because one or more matching certificates are already loaded","domain":"mydomain","server_name":"srv0"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9525318,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9552448,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling HTTP/3 listener","addr":":32779"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.956028,"logger":"tls","msg":"cleaning storage unit","storage":"FileStorage:/data/caddy"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.956899,"logger":"tls","msg":"finished cleaning storage units"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9578297,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"srv0","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9581263,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"remaining_auto_https_redirects","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9586885,"msg":"autosaved config (load with --resume flag)","file":"/config/caddy/autosave.json"}
{"level":"info","ts":1705198357.9586966,"msg":"serving initial configuration"}
```

But the server is still not reachable

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the port after the server name to the first port assigned by Plesk.

```
{$SERVER_NAME:plesk_server:first_assigned_port}
```